# Can't find the foreign key using Join for method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two tables: Category (Parent) and Product (Children).

I could use inner join with LINQ query syntax. But with method syntax, I could not get. `p.` doesn't load `CategoryID`

```
var db = new NorthwindEntities();
        var cats = db.Categories;
        var prods = db.Products;

        var catProducts1 = from c in db.Categories
                           join p in db.Products
                           on c.CategoryID equals p.CategoryID
                           select new { c.CategoryName, p.ProductName };

        var catProducts2 = db.Categories
                .Join(db.Products, c=>c.CategoryID,p=>p);
```

Comment: Does this work `var catProducts2 = db.Categories
                .Join(db.Products, c => c.CategoryID,p => p.CategoryID, (c, p) = new {CategoryName = c.CategoryName, ProductName = p.ProductName}).Select(s => new {c, p});`?

Comment: ... with method syntax, I could not get p. I haven't got the faintest idea what you mean. Next sentence: doesn't load CategoryId. What doesn't load CategoryId? The p that you could not get? Please rephrase your question. A proper unambiguous requirement would be nice. Code that works is not a requirement

Comment: @user1672994 thanks. my bad. I miss out the lambda after `p`. But now, `(c,p)` says 'The name 'c' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Steve - It was typo after (c, p). It should be `=>`. I've posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the correct syntax of `Join` lamda syntax for your scenario:

```
var catProducts2 = db.Categories.Join(db.Products, 
                     c => c.CategoryId, 
                     p => p.CategoryID, 
                    (c, p) => new { c.CategoryName, p.ProductName })
                  .Select(s => new { s.CategoryName, s.ProductName });
```

You can check the usage of above query at fiddle -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/C3N2I2